# Short story about Tibetan monks who want to know the name of God?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, religion, metaphysics

I can't remember the title or the author of the following story:

Some Tibetan monks want to know the name of God. They buy a supercomputer in order to calculate the name. Then...

> ...they find the name, and in the end of the story, all stars stop shining.

Comment: I edited your title and removed the second question about an unrelated story. Please remember your questions on this site must: a- have a specific title, and b- ask one and only one thing. Feel free to ask about the other story in a separate question :)

Comment: Now I'm interested in the second story as well - was it reposted as a different question?

Comment: @SqlRyan if Martin doesn't, you're always free to repost 2nd the question yourself.

Comment: Reminds me of (but isn't) Frederic Brown's story "Answer"

Comment: @DanNeely I did post it, and I'm hopeful I'll get the name! http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35419

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/234117/the-stars-started-going-out (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 62):

The story about the Tibetan monks who want to find the name of god is ["The Nine Billion Names of God"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God) by Arthur Clarke.

Comment: And there's an homage to this story in *Futurama's* "Godfellas" episode.

Comment: It was published, conveniently, in an anthology titled "The Nine Billion Names of God" :)