# Story about a factory that produces precious stones but nothing useful

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

[In the original question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35303/short-story-about-tibetan-monks-who-want-to-know-the-name-of-god), the OP also asked about a second story that was removed from the question, and I've got my interest piqued. I assume it's also a short story - can somebody help me find the story that's being referred to (t)here?

> A man (the last one in the world?) is lost in the wilderness, looking
>   for other living persons. Suddenly he find some kind of a factory, run
>   by robots. He hopes the factory produces things he can use. He asks
>   the robots to show him the products, and they shows him a lot of
>   precious stones, worth nothing for him in his situation.

Thanks!