# The stars started going out

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Two men were, as I recall, walking up a hill on some alien planet, discussing a religious group they had just installed a computer for. The group believed that when they had written down all of the possible names for god, then the universe would end.

They were getting near the end of their discussion when one man mentioned that, with their new computer, they should be getting done their task right about then. The other man, looking up at the night sky, sees that the stars were, quietly, starting to go out, one after another.

A rather old short story, as I recall, possible 70's or before.

Comment: Voting to reopen as it was closed against a Q&A without an accepted answer. This seems like the better Q&A, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is '[The Nine Billion Names of God](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God)' by Arthur C Clarke.

The technicians install and run a computer that prints all possible names of God for a religious order who believe that is the purpose of the world, and it will end once the job is done.

> ‘Well, they believe that when they have listed all His names – and they reckon that there are about nine billion of them – God’s purpose will be achieved. The human race will have finished what it was created to do, and there won’t be any point in carrying on.

The technicians don't believe it, but become uneasy in the face of devout faith and delay completion of the work until they leave.

> I don’t see that it makes the slightest difference to us. After all, we already knew that they were crazy.’
> [...]
> The transport calls in a week. OK – then all we need to do is to find something that needs replacing during one of the overhaul periods – something that will hold up the works for a couple of days. We’ll fix it, of course, but not too quickly. If we time matters properly, we can be down at the airfield when the last name pops out of the register.

As they travel to the airport the computer finishes and they see the stars go out.

> Overhead, without any fuss, the stars were going out.

Comment: It's worth adding that the location was not an alien planet, but somewhere in Asia (probably Sri Lanka, but I don't recall for sure).

Comment: @ThePhoton I remember it was in the Himalaya. Some Tibet-like realm.